# symfony 3 how to disable input in controller

Tags: php, symfony, input

So... I want to disable an input in Symfony 3.0.2 depending on IF statement in my controller. How do I do that? Setting value for example field first_name

```
            $form->get('firstname')->setData($fbConnect['data']['first_name']);
```

So I thought about something like ->setOption('disabled', true)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the form options, like you suggest, you can define your form type with something like :

```
class FormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('first_name',TextType::class,array('disabled'=>$option['first_name_disabled']));
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('first_name_disabled'=>false));
}
}
```

And then in your controller create the form with :

```
$form=$this->createForm(MyType::class, $yourEntity, array('first_name_disabled'=>$disableFirstNameField));
```

But if the value of disabled depends on the value in the entity, you should rather use a formevent :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('first_name',TextType::class);

    // Here an example with PreSetData event which disables the field if the value is not null :
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,function(FormEvent $event){
        $lastName = $event->getData()->getLastName();

        $event->getForm()->add('first_name',TextType::class,array('disabled'=>($lastName !== null)));
    });
}
```

Comment: Great tip on using the form event, it's easy to forget they exist.

Answer (score 1):

#### Another way to change Symfony Form field in a Controller

I use below code to change my form without use `FormEvents`.
After building `$form` just get all configs and do changes, remove the field and re-creating using new `$attrs`

> NOTE: I'm using **Symfony 4**

```
$form = $this->createForm(YourEntityFormType::class, $yourEntity);
// Change one or more fields through certain condition
if (true === SOME_CONDITION) {
    $field = $form->get('your_field');
    $attrs = $field->getConfig()->getOptions();
    $attrs['attr']['readonly'] ='readonly';
    $attrs['disabled'] ='disabled';
    $form->remove($field->getName());
    $form->add($field->getName(),
         get_class($field->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType()),
         $attrs);
}
```

Remember to do it before call `$form->handleRequest()`